# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup api.tutorialmate.com on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-route53, kops

I want to set up `Kubernetes Cluster` on AWS using `kops`.

I have domain `tutorialmate.com`. I have added Nameserver provided by `Route53`.

Used below command to create cluseter:

`kops create cluster --name=tutorialmate.com --state=s3://kop-state-009 --zones=eu-west-1a --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.micro --dns-zone=tutorialmate.com`

Updated Cluster :
`kops update cluster tutorialmate.com --yes --state=s3://kop-state-009`

But when trying to get nodes : `kubectl get nodes`

Getting below error :

> **Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup api.tutorialmate.com on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host**

I should get details of nodes. I can see **3 EC2 instance** are running under `eu-west-1a`. But getting the error as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

probaly your local system dns can't resolve this name, so you put in hosts manualy this entry:
Eg. on Windows
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

#Ip of AzureKubernetes service 
172.20.xx.xx   xxx-dns-xxxxxxxxx.privatelink.xxxx.azmk8s.io

Answer (score 0):

even I also got the same error, so I changed API server endpoint access from private to the public then it's working fine.

But I guess this is not the correct way so still, I am finding the proper solution with private mode.

Comment: Abhishek Jalan, Have you found the solution, i am also facing this same issue.
What did you mean by changing API server endpoint access